# How to integrate method into a class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Please bear with me - OOP and Python are very new things for me.

I've a class that looks like this:

```py
class Offer():
    def __init__(self, active=False, kind=None, added=None,
                area=None, city=None, street=None, coords=None, phone=None,
                size=None, ... many more attributes
                ):
        self.active = active
        self.added = added
        self.kind = kind
        self.area = area
        self.city = city
        self.street = street
        self.coords = coords
        self.phone = phone
        self.size = size
        ...
        many more attributes
```

I would like to have this structure as **nested** dict so I've added this to Offer()

```py
# continue of previous block

@property
    def dictionary(self):
        d = {
            'active' : self.active,
            'added' : self.added,
            'kind' : self.kind, 
            'address' : {
                'area' : self.area,
                'city' : self.city,
                'street' : self.street,
                'coords' : self.coords
            },
            'params' : {
                'size' : self.size,
                'phone' : self.phone,
            }
            ...
            many more nested dict
        return d
```

I want the user to use this class as follows:

```py
>>> a = Offer(active=True, added=12.11.19, kind="kind", city="some city", street="some street", phone=123456789)

>>> print(a.dictionary)

{ 'active' : True, 'added' : 12.11.19, 'kind' : "kind", 'address' : { 'city' : "some city", 'street' : "some street"    }, 'params' : { 'phone' : 123456789 } }
```

I want to only return values that are **not None** and use my custom hierarchy for the data.

I've found that this bit of code which works just fine for what I need.

```py
a = Offer(phone=123456789, size=50, city="city", kind='kind')

def remove_none(obj):
  if isinstance(obj, (list, tuple, set)):
    return type(obj)(remove_none(x) for x in obj if x is not None)
  elif isinstance(obj, dict):
    return type(obj)((remove_none(k), remove_none(v))
      for k, v in obj.items() if k is not None and v is not None)
  else:
    return obj

print(remove_none(a.dictionary))
```

**My question is: How do I integrate remove_none to @property so that it executes automaticaly?**

Maybe I'm thinking all wrong here but if anyone could point me into right direction it would help me tremendously.

Comment: Change `return d` to `return remove_none(d)`...?

Comment: I feel really stupid right now. Thank you.

Comment: It looks like your problem is solved. I thought you want the `remove_none` logic inside your `dictionary` method. I did not think it'd be that simple so I wrote all that code below lol. We all make mistakes. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Some extra information first. The dict representation that you want of your class can already be found using [`vars(object)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars) or `object.__dict__`.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, x=None, y=10, z=20):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         self.z = z
...
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo(1, 2, 3)
>>> vars(f1)
{'x': None, 'y': 10, 'z': 20}
>>> vars(f2)
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> f1.__dict__
{'x': None, 'y': 10, 'z': 20}
```

The generation of the `dict` representation of an object can be controlled by implementing `__setattr__` inside the class.

```
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, x=None, y=10, z=20):
...         self.x = x
...         self.y = y
...         self.z = z
...     def __setattr__(self, name, value):
...         if value is not None:
...             self.__dict__[name] = value
...
>>> f1 = Foo()
>>> f2 = Foo(1, 2, 3)
>>> vars(f1)
{'y': 10, 'z': 20}
>>> vars(f2)
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> f1.__dict__
{'y': 10, 'z': 20}
```

Since you want a custom `dict` structure, you can loop through all the instance variables of the class and add values to the dict if the value is not None.

```
@property
def dictionary(self):
    d = {
        'address': {}, 
        'params': {}
    }
    address = {'area', 'city', 'street', 'coords'}
    params = {'size', 'phone'}

    for k, v in self.__dict__.items():
        if v is None:
            continue

        if k in address:
            d['address'][k] = v
        elif k in params:
            d['params'][k] = v
        else:
            d[k] = v

    return d
```

Comment: *"The dict representation that you want of your class can already be found using vars(object) or object.__dict__"* Umm, no? The OP's dict is nested.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I have edited my answer. Perhaps this is an easier approach to ignore `None` values while also creating a custom dict.

Comment: Ok, so this is very comprehensive answer that goes much deeper than my current understanding. However - I've been fumbing with `__dict__` and tried something like that before:

`@property
        def dictionary(self):
            dictionary = { k:v for k, v in self.__dict__.items() if v != None }
        return dictionary`

However this did not go well with dict that has other values than dict.

Comment: You can share the entire implementation of your class and what kind of dictionary you want so that we can help you with exactly what you want. Edit your question and leave a comment here so that I get notified that you edited your question.

Comment: Acctualy for this code to work I needed to do two things - put remove_none funtion inside @property dictionary method and return remove_none(d) instead of return d.